# Ram Memory Usage for Windows Application

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a project using windows application VB.net Framework. I would like to inquire about how to control the RAM usage , memory usage for the application as i would not want to jam up my clients computer. Is there any codes that is available for grabs ? I have been looking around but couldnt find any.

Thank you

Comment: `My.Application.Info.WorkingSet`

Answer (score 6):

What have you tried so far? It should work something like this:

```
Dim x As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()

Dim inf As String
inf = "Mem Usage: " & x.WorkingSet / 1024 & " K" & vbCrLf _
    & "Paged Memory: " & x.PagedMemorySize / 1024 & " K"

MessageBox.Show(inf, "Memory Usage")
```

Feel free to adjust to your needs.

Comment: Hi thanks alot for your reply, this only shows the memory used ? it doesnt controls the memory usage ?

Comment: What do you mean by controling it? To control it you have to code in a memory "friendly" fashion, like don't allocate too much for variables and such.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Erm.. Issit possible for me to actually allocate them like for example i have 3 application running and this particular one whereby im coding, i want it to not take up all my resources at once cause sometimes if it does it actually hangs my computer so ill want my other 3 application to be unaffected. Thank you.

Comment: This question cannot be answered very specific. First of all it should be determined if the applications really should consume that much memory (bug or feature). If they don't need it, it should be fixed in the applications itself. If they all _really_ need it, then the administration of this enviroment should make sure to provide the memory necessary. It shouldn't be the task of a program to take care of one other programs memory.

Comment: Hmm,.. thats why if its possible i would like to set them to a number like maybe 1024mb of memory and not anything above that, so the application will run at that constraint.? So am i right to say we dont exactly have that kind of sorcery ?

Comment: Like I said, this should be done with an administrative aspect. There are tools out there like Process Lasso oder Process Tamer which can help with that. Alternatively, you could run each program on a virtual machine and allocate the memory to each virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Bjoern great help :D